# When running a for-loop with n iterations (in R), is there an easy way to average the time of each command across all iterations?

Tags: r, runtime

Let's say I have a for loop that looks something like this:

```
n <- 1000
for (i in 1:n) {
   command1 <- solve(matrix1)
   command2 <- solve(matrix2)
   ...
   commandP <- solve(matrixP)
   
   matrix1 <- update(matrix1)
   matrix2 <- update(matrix2)
   ...
   matrixP <- update(matrixP)
}
```

So basically, I am solving for the inverse of P matrices, then updating each matrix and proceeding to iterate through again, about 1000 times.

I want to get the average computation time for inverting each of the P matrices (that is, averaged across all 1000 iterations). Some matrices are big and take a few seconds to invert; others are small and take a matter of microseconds.

Is there a simple built-in function that can accomplish this?

I know I could time each line manually using the Sys.time() command, but this would be tedious and extremely messy in the code because I would have to add a line before and after each matrix calculation.

Answer (score 1):

To get the time taken to run each matrix conversion, you could set up a list of expressions and run these using `eval`.
This is a bit of a quick-and-dirty approach tha occurs to me - but it might be a solution...

```
list.of.functions = list(
 matrix1 = expression(cor(matrix(rnorm(100), ncol = 10))), # Quick
 matrix2 = expression(cor(matrix(rnorm(1000), ncol = 100))), # Slow
 matrix3 = expression(cor(matrix(rnorm(10000), ncol = 1000))) # Slower
)
elapsed = list.of.functions # Copy the size and anes (R takes care of casting to the new data type)
for(f in names(list.of.functions)){
    elapsed[[f]] = system.time({eval(list.of.functions[[f]])})["elapsed"]
}
do.call("rbind", elapsed)
```

If you save such an output as a `data.frame` with a column for each iteration, you could run `rowMeans` over it to get average runtimes for each matrix.

```
# Set up empty data.frame for the timing results
elapsed.df = as.data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow = length(list.of.functions), ncol = n))
rownames(elapsed.df) = names(list.of.functions)
# Outer loop of iterations
for(i in seq_len(n)){
    # Inner loop of function evaluations
    for(f in names(list.of.functions)){
        elapsed.df[f, i] = system.time({eval(list.of.functions[[f]])})["elapsed"]
    }
}
rowMeans(elapsed.df)
```

Hard to explain in more detail without a minimal example.

Comment: Have a look at my edited answer - I misread your question the first time round...